# Stop reload of page when clicking a link leading to php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to implement some sort of news module on my website. The news is contained in a text file that I parse with php and display on the site. Some of these news have links "Details..." which should take me to a php script which will show the detailed text of that news item. I know how I could accomplish this with javascript, but I need to do it without using javascript. I want my page to not reload when taken to this script.

For example:

This is a news item:

```
echo '<article class="newsContainer">';
echo '<img src="' . $sadrzaj[3] . '" class="news_image" alt=" ">';
echo '<h1 class="news_header">' . ucfirst(strtolower($sadrzaj[2])) . '</h1>';
echo '<p class="news_item">' . $opis . '</p>';
if($imaDetaljnije) echo '<a href="/servis/Struktura/index.php?detaljnije="' .$detaljnije . '"&naslov="' .ucfirst(strtolower($sadrzaj[2])) . '"&" class="detaljnijeLink">Detaljnije...</a>';
echo '</article>';
```

This is the script I normally use to load a page using AJAX and to write it to the document:

```
function AjaxLoadJQuery(pageToLoad){
        var requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        requestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (requestObject.readyState == 4 && requestObject.status == 200)
            {
                document.open();
                document.write(requestObject.responseText);
                document.close();
            }
            if (requestObject.readyState == 4 && requestObject.status == 404)
            {
                alert('belaj');
            }
        };
        requestObject.open("GET", pageToLoad, true);
        requestObject.send();
    }
```

I pass it the url of the page and the content of my page changes.

Now I'd like to preserve this sort of Single page application model, but clicking this link would cause a page reload.

Is there any way I can do this, using javascript?

Comment: You have to [prevent the default event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Any way without javascript?

Comment: You're using JavaScript. Do you have a reason for not using JavaScript?

Comment: What if the user disables javascript in the browser?

Comment: Then the page will reload. You cannot do what you want to do without JavaScript.

Comment: If I cannot, any other options besides the current answer which opens a new tab?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href="link_to_page.php" onClick="window.open(this.href); return false;" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Any way without javascript?

Comment: The "return false" would stop the browser navigation, but first it would allow it open the content in the "Details..." link

Comment: @Matsura This is the only way that I could think of.

Comment: This opens a new tab in Chrome, is this the standard behavior?

Comment: Yes, window.open would open a new tab (or window) and would navigate to the link in the anchor tag